# Why is elastic search client pointing to a different index while performing a search query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to do a search operation on ElasticSearch. But when I call the search query , the client is pointing to some other index(which I have used previously).

This is how I'm doing my settings.

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="url" value="http://localhost:9200" />
</appSettings>

            configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];
            var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configvalue1));
            var defaultIndex = "abc";

            settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
            client = new ElasticClient(settings);


            if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
                client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

            var createIndexResponse =
                client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex);

            return client;
```

I'm using this client for some search operation.

```
string query = @"{
                            ""query"": {
                                ""bool"": {
                                    ""should"": [
                                        {
                                            ""match"": {
                                            ""title"": {0}
                                                        }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            ""match"": {
                                            ""content"": {0}
                                                        }
                                        }
                                     ]
                                    }
                                 }};

string a = query.Replace("{0}", "apple");
var callResult = client.LowLevel.Search<string>(a);
```

When I check the callResult,I'm getting a result from the documents that are indexed in a different index(for eg: zzz). Is there anything I have to do regarding this?

TIA

Comment: Please post full example where and how you construct "a"

Comment: what's the value of `configvalue1`? It looks like you're not setting the default index on connection settings to `defaultIndex`. What is the value of `a` in your search call? Where are you setting the index name?

Comment: @RussCam ...I edited the post and updated few values. When i added the  index name during the low level search call , its working correctly. In that case, do i still have to add the index to the connectionsettings??

Comment: The documentation on index name inference has the details - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index-name-inference.html. default index name on connection settings is used if no index is specified for the type (using `.MapDefaultTypeIndices()` or on the request directly

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're not telling Elastic to only search your "abc" index, you're telling it to query every index on localhost port 9200.

All you need to do is A. declare your index name var first, and then B. append it (with a /) to the Uri you are are creating, such that you only querying within that index. I've refactored the first three lines below:

```
        var defaultIndex = "abc";
        configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"] + "/" + defaultIndex;
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configvalue1));
```

Now, you are generating a Uri to go to server/port/index directly.

Now keep in mind, this will break your delete/create index call, which should be another call - define the Index name, pass it to a call to drop/create your index (via the URL) and then you can create a query Uri with the edited example.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually i figured it out. Though I'm creating an index, I'm never assigning it to the client as u said. So is the behavior ... Thanks again for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why it is running on a different index. Its because, even though I created an index I never assigned it to the client. So is the behavior. So I added the index to the settings.

```
configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];
            var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configvalue1));
            var defaultIndex = "abc";

            settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)*.DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);*
            client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```